# Visual Studio Code - Find and Replace a function call without losing string parameter value

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, replace, replaceall

Have a bit of an issue. I need to replace all the console.log lines so that they match a logger function I have created.

Currently there is:

```
console.log("log message");
```

End result needed:

```
logger("log message","d");
```

Is there a way I can find and replace the start and end of the console log line without losing the message?

Using Visual Studio Code but can use other tools if needed.

Comment: https://dev.to/rfornal/vs-code-search-and-replace-regex-mn2

Comment: @luk2302 had a look at those. 

Currently trying to use console.log(.+?); followed with logger$1 however it gives me the group as being the whole ("log message") instead of  just "log message". I have tried adding more brackets but have seemed to become stuck.

Comment: Try `console.log\((.+?)\);` - `(` and `)` are considered regex symbol and need to be escaped.

Comment: @luk2302 just remembered that, Had the solution a minute before you replied. Thank you every much!